# How to Create an HTML element exactly above another one?

Tags: javascript, position

Given an HTML element displayed somewhere on a page ?

how can I make another html so that it completely overlaps it ?

To give an idea, I tried something like this but it does not work if the HTML element in input is at a bottom of a page and I need to scrolldown to reach it

```
function createOverlap(elem) {
    var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    over.style.position = 'absolute';
    over.style.top =    rect.top+'px';
    over.style.left=    rect.left+'px';
    over.style.height = rect.height+'px';
    over.style.width=   rect.width+'px';
    return over;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle link of it so we can check it.?

Comment: Do you mean "exactly **hiding** another one"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that 'over' is a DOM element, other than that, you are very close.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7em2g/

```
function createOverlap(elem) {
    var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    var over = document.createElement('div');
    over.style.position = 'absolute';
    over.style.top =    rect.top+'px';
    over.style.left=    rect.left+'px';
    over.style.height = rect.height+'px';
    over.style.width=   rect.width+'px';
    return over;
}
var bar = createOverlap(document.getElementById('foo'));
bar.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255,0,0,0.3)';
document.body.appendChild(bar);
```

Um It doesn't make a difference if you scroll down here. If you are still having troubles we're going to need more information about the problem.